# write the value at specific location of property file using servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, properties

**************THIS IS MY CONTROLLER(SERVLET)****************************

```
        package com.igate.controller; 
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.lang.reflect.Method;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Properties;
        import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
        import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
        import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;

        public class TestController extends HttpServlet {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            public TestController() {                   
            }                           
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                doPost(request, response);
            }               
            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
                System.out.println("TEst---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                String action= request.getParameter("action");
                System.out.println(action);
            if(action.equals("proceed"))
            {
                String pf =request.getParameter("pf");              
                System.out.println(pf);
          FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/SCT_WRK/projectOne/src/framework.properties");
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
          String line = "";
         String newTxt = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
             if ((line.trim()).equals("{PLATFORM_END}")){//if line has the match you need
                   line = pf+ "="+ pf; + "\n" + "{PLATFORM_END}";//insert new text
          }
               newTxt += line + "\n";
              FileWriter fw = new FileWriter ("D:/SCT_WRK/projectOne/src/framework.properties");
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
               bw.write(newTxt);
      br.close();
       bw.close();
      fr.close();
       fw.close();  
            }
            }
            }
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

THIS IS MY JSP PAGE ********

```
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
            <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form method="post" action="TestController">
        <table align="center">
        <tr><th>Enter the Platform</th><td> <input type="text" name="pf"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="proceed" name="action" id ="p"> </td>
        </tr>
           </table>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

THIS IS MY PROPERTY FILE******

```
        WORKING_DIR = com/test/auto/framework
        LIB = lib

        PLATFORM = {WINDOWS}
        APP_TYPE = {WEB}

        PLATFORM_START={START}
        WINDOWS = WINDOWS
        MAC = MAC
        ANDROID = ANDROID
        IOS = IOS
        PLATFORM_END={END}

        WEB = WEB
        NATIVE = NATIVE
        HYBRID = HYBRID


        PLATFORM_VERSION = 4.4.2
        DEVICE = GalaxyS4
        DEFAULT_URL = http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub
        GRID_URL = http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

        IE_WEBDRIVER_PATH = {LIB}/IEDriverServer.exe
        CHROME_WEBDRIVER_PATH = {LIB}/chromedriver.exe
        IE_WEBDRIVER = IEDriverServer.exe
        CHROME_WEBDRIVER = chromedriver.exe

        BROWSER_PROFILE_PATH = {LIB}/{BROWSER}/Profile

        SAFARI_EXTENSION = {LIB}/{SAFARI}/Extension/extension.js
        FIREFOX_AUTOAUTH_EXTENSION = {LIB}/{FIREFOX}/Extension/autoauth-2.1-fx+fn.xpi

        USE_FIREFOX_AUTOAUTH = false

        EXEC_SPEED_CONTROLLER_SECONDS = 1

        LOG_WAIT_MESSAGES = false

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

1).     I need what is user enter in a platform input text it should be write in the property file exact before " {PLATFORM_END}" 
        example.. user enter "LINUX"
        it should be write here-      PLATFORM_START={START}
                                       WINDOWS = WINDOWS
                                        MAC = MAC
                                        ANDROID = ANDROID
                                       IOS = IOS
                        here------->   LINUX =LINUX
                                      PLATFORM_END={END}

2). I want all user entered platform should be append at bottom of platform list and before     {PLATFORM_END} .

how is it possible.?. if anyone know logic please help .. 
    thanks in advance

Comment: Poorly formulated question, and poor formatting, -1. Please don't post yards of blank lines here, and please don't post yards of code that are mostly irrelevant there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Apache common config already have this feature. But with Java IO, you can read the config file line by line and rewrite each line with addition of your new line:

```
String pf = request.getParameter("pf");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/SCT_WRK/projectOne/src/framework.properties");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = "";
    String newTxt = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if ((line.trim()).contains("PLATFORM_END={END}"))
        {// if line has the match you need
            line = pf + "=" + pf + "\n" + "PLATFORM_END={END}";// insert new
                                                            // text
        }
        newTxt += line + "\n";
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:/SCT_WRK/projectOne/src/framework.properties");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    bw.write(newTxt);
    br.close();
    bw.close();
    fr.close();
    fw.close();
```

Comment: yeah I updated my servlet with your code .. neither it is  showing any error ,nor It is updating property file .

Comment: I meant, can you update this post with your updated servlet code. So I could take a look.

Comment: I updated my servlet. can you tell what's going wrong ?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. The reason code didn't work previously was that you have changed your configuration from {PLATFORM_END} to PLATFORM_END={END}. Thus it didn't see the matching. Update your code with the updated answer, and it should work now.